# check if an window closed in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to check if an window is closed or not.
Here is my example,

I have opened a new window by calling this function,

```
$scope.openwind= function(){
    $scope.popupWindow = $window.open("index.html#/channelintegration", "SOme Title", 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no');
}
```

Then I have been checking if the opened window (popupWindow)  is closed or not, by calling below function through a button click,

```
$scope.checkmywindow=function(){
    console.log($scope.popupWindow);
    console.log($scope.popupWindow.closed);
}
```

Now, I need to check if the window (popupWindow) is closed or not, without the button trigger.

Pls Help on this.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sravan , Thank you for your answer.. It really helped a lot for doing further stuffs.. Now i used below code to check automatically whether the window is closed or not, using $interval service in angular.. 
This will update a scope variable (windowstatus) every second automatically, with respect to the current status of the window (popupWindow)..

```
    $scope.checkwind = function(){
                if (!$scope.popupWindow) {
                     $scope.windowstatus = "Window hasn't opened yet";

} else {
if ($scope.popupWindow.closed) {

         $scope.windowstatus = "Window is Currently Closed"
        } 
        else {

         $scope.windowstatus = "Window is Currently Open";
    } 
}
console.log($scope.windowstatus);
}
$interval( function(){ $scope.checkwind(); }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `window is opened or not`, by taking `window.open` function in a scope variable and check using the scope.

```
$scope.openwind= function(){
    $scope.popupWindow = $window.open("index.html#/channelintegration", "SOme Title", 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no');
}

$scope.closewind= function(){
    if ($scope.popupWindow) {
          $scope.popupWindow.close();
      }
    // code for closing goes here

}

$scope.checkmywindow=function(){
    if (!$scope.popupWindow) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "'$scope.popupWindow' has never been opened!";
    } else {
        if ($scope.popupWindow.closed) {
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "'$scope.popupWindow' has been closed!";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "'$scope.popupWindow' has Opened!";
        }
    }
}
```

[Check this link and implement](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_closed)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sravan.. But, this will apply only when we programmatically close the window through any trigger.. The case here is, i need to check automatically whether the window is closed or not..

Comment: @ManushJ, I have updated my answer and given a reference, please check. you have to implement the same using angular. Ask me if any doubts.

Comment: @Manush J, checked the answer?

Comment: Now, i modified the 'checkmywindow' function and made it to call at the time interval,

Comment: $scope.callAtInterval = function() {
            if (!$scope.popupWindow) {
  console.log($scope.popupWindow+"never been opened");
    } else {
        if ($scope.popupWindow.closed) {
   console.log($scope.popupWindow+"never been closed");
        } else {
   console.log($scope.popupWindow+"has opened");
        }
    }

    }
 $interval( function(){ $scope.callAtInterval(); }, 3000);

Comment: whre did you put the `console.log`

Comment: Check below links, where i added the scrn shots of the code and console, i'm having..

http://manush-venkatesh.esy.es/temp/code.jpg

http://manush-venkatesh.esy.es/temp/intervalerror.jpg

Comment: if ($scope.popupWindow.closed) {
    if ($scope.$storage.name != "success") {
        $scope.integrationstatus = "cancel";
    } else {
        $scope.integrationstatus = "success";
    }
} else {
    $scope.integrationstatus = "inprogress";
}
}
}
$interval(function() {
    $scope.checkwind();
}, 100);

Comment: once open your snippet and click that button

Comment: @Manush J, pls accept or vote my asnswer if you find it useful